# jQuery click tab to open and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some tabs that I'm using as navigation and it's working fine apart from one bit of functionality, The tabs are closed by default and only open once clicked, what I want is to be able to click on the tab again to close the panel with the content. I know this will probably be really easy but I'm not a jQuery developer so I'm struggling a bit.

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');

$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

$(this).addClass('current');
$("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
```

})

})

you can see the full working tabs [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7jdumm7/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1) You would only need to `.removeClass()` from tab content and li element which are not going to be targeted in current click.

2) Use `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');

    jQuery('ul.tabs li').not('[data-tab='+tab_id+']').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('.tab-content:not(#'+tab_id+')').removeClass('current');

    jQuery(this).toggleClass('current');
    jQuery("#" + tab_id).toggleClass('current');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rfge06/)**

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var el = "";
    jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');
        jQuery('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        jQuery('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        if(tab_id != el){
          jQuery(this).addClass('current');
        jQuery("#" + tab_id).addClass('current'); 
        }

       el = tab_id;       



    })



})
```